# jquery: How to empty a form field, then bring focus/cursor to it?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that I'm submitting with AJAX.  A user fills out the field (called "barcode") and hits return, and the form submits.

After the form submits, they are shown a success or failure message.  I want to:

1. Fade out the message
2. Empty the 'barcode' field
3. Bring the cursor back to the field, ready for the next person.

So far I have got step 1 handled:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('span.login-fail').parent().fadeOut('normal'); }, 1000); 
setTimeout(function(){ $('span.login-welcome').parent().fadeOut('normal'); }, 1000);
```

But I do not know how to do 2 or 3.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To clear a field just use `$("#fieldID").val("")` which will set the value to nothing.
- Focus is done just by using the focus method `$("#fieldID").focus()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$( "#form_id").find( "input").val( "").end( ).find( "input:first").focus();
```

this will clean all inputs in the form and move focus to the first one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var barcode = $('#barcode');
barcode.val('');
barcode.focus();
```